# remove certain words in field within the mapbox gl expression by zoom level

Tags: expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

My data is looking like this

| name |
| --- |
| Atlanta City |
| Paris City |
| London City |
| ... |

I want to get rid of the 'City' and not showing on my maps from Zlv 0-10, so only the city name itself shows on maps

and from Zlv 11 ~ i want to have the full name of the my table on the map.

Can anyone help how to start?

Comment: As someone who spent the last 30 minutes trying to solve that exact problem with city names I don't think there's a solution for this within Mapbox expressions. You just have to preprocess the data :(

Answer (score 0):

I used Zoom and Property Function

also instead of slicing them, i did concat.

I did what i needed to do here is an example of my expression

```json
[
  "step",
  ["zoom"],
  [
    "match",
    ["get", "category"],
    [110106],
    ["to-string", ["get", "name"]],
    ["to-string", ["get", "name"]]
  ],
  11,
  [
    "match",
    ["get", "category"],
    [110106],
    ["concat", ["get", "name"], "TEXT I NEED TO CONCAT"],
    ["to-string", ["get", "name"]]
  ]
]
```